# Distributing sequential array items as mixed

Tags: php, arrays, forms

I have an ordered list from 1 to 15. I put these list items in a form and assigned a checkbox to each. An user can choose whatever he wishes from the items in this form.

When the user fills in and sends the form, I want to separate this list under certain headings.

For example:

```
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="checklist[]"> Option 1
    <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="checklist[]"> Option 2
    <input type="checkbox" value="3" name="checklist[]"> Option 3 
    <input type="checkbox" value="4" name="checklist[]"> Option 4
    <input type="checkbox" value="5" name="checklist[]"> Option 5
    <input type="checkbox" value="6" name="checklist[]"> Option 6
    <input type="checkbox" value="7" name="checklist[]"> Option 7
    <input type="checkbox" value="8" name="checklist[]"> Option 8
    <input type="checkbox" value="9" name="checklist[]"> Option 9
    <input type="checkbox" value="10" name="checklist[]"> Option 10
    <input type="checkbox" value="11" name="checklist[]"> Option 11
    <input type="checkbox" value="12" name="checklist[]"> Option 12
    <input type="checkbox" value="13" name="checklist[]"> Option 13
    <input type="checkbox" value="14" name="checklist[]"> Option 14
    <input type="checkbox" value="15" name="checklist[]"> Option 15
</form>
```

According to the results you choose:

**Category A**
Questions in this category: 1 - 3 - 4 - 10
You selected: 3 - 4 - 10

**Category B**
Questions in this category: 2 - 8 - 11 - 14 - 15
You selected: 2 - 8 - 11

**Category C**
Questions in this category: 5 - 6 - 7 - 9 - 12 - 13
You selected: 5 - 7 - 12 - 13

Can you give me an idea of how I can do this?

Comment: What is a relation between this form and your categories?

Comment: @splash58 I try to make an analysis according to the answers of the users. There are different questions in my list. Users answer these questions and give me feedback. Each question is about 3 categories in total. However, I cannot ask questions from a category repeatedly. This reduces the reliability of the test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to the question I asked by searching. For those who need help with this, I add it here.

First, make the options of each category into an array.

```
$category_A = array (1, 3, 4, 10);
$category_B = array (2, 8, 11, 14, 15);
$category_C = array (5, 6, 7, 9, 12, 13)
```

Then insert these arrays into the foreach loop and check if the selected options are in this array. An example for category A:

```
foreach ( $category_A as $value ) {

    if ( in_array( $value, $_POST['check_list'] ) ){

        echo '<span class="selected">'. $value .'</span>';

    } else {

        echo '<span>'. $value .'</span>';

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When the user completes the form, you receive in the php backend what is inside the value statement of the optionbox. So do a simple foreach for the array you get with if statements

Comment: Yes, I can make a simple foreach, but I don't want to show the selected ones in order. I want to separate them into different categories.

Comment: Use arrays to put them in the diferent categories and print them in your desired order

Comment: Actually, I want to show the questions in that category and the answers chosen by the user at the same time. I updated the question, can you check it?